# How can an explicit formula for the envelope to an oscillatory damped function be obained?

Tags: plotting, fitting

So I have the function

```
f=(2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]
   Cos[(t \[Alpha] \[Beta])/2] Cosh[(t^2 \[Alpha]^2)/(
   8 b^2)])/Sqrt[b^2] - (
 2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]
   Cos[(t \[Alpha] \[Beta])/2] Sinh[(t^2 \[Alpha]^2)/(
   8 b^2)])/Sqrt[b^2]
```

which I have produced a plot of using

```
Manipulate[Plot[(2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]
     Cos[(t \[Alpha] \[Beta])/2] Cosh[(t^2 \[Alpha]^2)/(8 b^2)])/Sqrt[
   b^2] - (2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]
     Cos[(t \[Alpha] \[Beta])/2] Sinh[(t^2 \[Alpha]^2)/(8 b^2)])/Sqrt[
   b^2], {t, -6.63871, 6.63867}], {b, -3.55345, 
  3.55349}, {\[Alpha], -2, 2}, {\[Beta], -2, 2}]
```

My goal is to find an explicit formula for the *upper* envelope of the function, but I am totally unsure how to do so. I know I could convert the function to a list of data, but I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution consistst of products of an oscillating  Cos t and and a difference of Cosh t^2 and Sinh t^2 producing the maximal amplitude at cos =+-1, symmetric in +-t.

```
g[t_]=f // Together // PowerExpand // FullSimplify
(2 E^(-((t^2 \[Alpha]^2)/(8 b^2))) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Cos[(t \[Alpha] \[Beta])/2])/b
```

Simply set Cos[_]:>1 and b->Abs[b]

```
Manipulate[
Plot[{(2 E^(-((t^2 \[Alpha]^2)/(8 b^2))) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Cos[(t \[Alpha] \[Beta])/2])/b,
(2 E^(-((t^2 \[Alpha]^2)/(8 b^2))) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]])/Abs[b]},
{t,-6.63871,6.63867}],
{b,-3.55345,3.55349},{\[Alpha],-2,2},{\[Beta],-2,2}]
```

[image]